# I made my first class, why doesnt it work?

Tags: php, class, oop

I tried using my first class but it isnt working i am completely new to coding so i dont know how it works

ive tried looking on the internet and changing some things

Here is the php file:

```
new Products();

foreach ($products->getProduct() as $product) {
    echo $product . '<br>';
}
```

here is the class

```
<?php

class Products
{

    public function getProducts()
    {
        [
            'apple',
            'orange',
            'pitaya',
            'tomato',
            'banana',
        ];
    }

}
```

the result when i try my code is this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Products' not found in index.php:3
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in index.php on line 3

Comment: When I was totally new to coding I was looking up tutorials. There are many regarding this.

Comment: If you have time ,please follow this link. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm

Answer (score 1):

Here is code:

```
    include(__dir__.'/Products.php');
    $products = new Products();
    $allProducts = $products->getProduct();
    if($allProducts)
    foreach ($allProdcuts as $product) {
        echo $product . '<br>';
        }
     }
```

You need to include class file before the call it

Comment: Also mention that php-file with class __should be included__, I suppose OP didn't do it. Also `getProducts` function __must return__ value.

Comment: It still gives me the same error as before: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Products' not found in index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in index.php on line 3

Comment: @feeeesssiiee you need to `include`  class file before call it. Check updated answer

Comment: @feeeesssiiee where are the files located? In the same directory or somewhere else?

Comment: files are located at the same place did what everything said but its still not working

Comment: i now also have included the file and returned it but still got an error

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the class Products isn't found.
For test purpose you can do something like this (declare the class then use it right after) :

```
<?php
    class Products {

    public function getProducts()
    {
        return [
            'apple',
            'orange',
            'pitaya',
            'tomato',
            'banana',
        ];
    }
    }

    $products = new Products();

    foreach ($products->getProduct() as $product) {
        echo $product . '<br>';
    }
```

Good luck in your learnings ;)

Comment: Right, I've edited, a missing return (that say "return this to the caller".

Comment: thanks for ur awnser but i coudnt get it working got an error that said:
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Products::getProduct() in index.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in index.php on line 26

Comment: Humm, the function name isn't the same (getProducts() on line 26)

Answer (score 1):

@feeeesssiiee, 
First you need to create a file named `Products.php` in the same directory (for convenience) as your `index.php`.
Now copy the code :

```
   class Products {

    public function getProducts()
    {
        return [
            'apple',
            'orange',
            'pitaya',
            'tomato',
            'banana',
        ];
    }

}
```

into `Products.php`.

Within `index.php` write following code :

```
include_once('Products.php');
$products = new Products();

$all_products = $products->getProducts();

if(!empty($all_products)) {
  foreach ( $all_products as $product) {
     echo $product . '<br>';
   }
}
```